# Toggle class and remove from other elements using a filter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to toggle between classes on a page with two sections :
when you click the first one, it toggle a class called `open` and removes it from the other section that eventually had it.

I've managed to make things work with the toggle, but the other `section` has not the class `open` removed.
So I started experimenting with the `.filter` but I can't manage to understand it...

**The behaviour:**
only one div should be red at the same time

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
const sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");

Array.from(sections).forEach(function(section) {
    section.addEventListener('click', function(el) {
        //console.log(sections, el)
        //var diff = sections.filter(element => element !== section)
        //console.log(diff)
        section.classList.toggle("open")
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;

}

main{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;   
}

section{
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    padding-top: 2em;
    flex-grow: 2;
    flex-basis: 0;
    display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

section:nth-child(1){
    background-color: lightblue;
}

section:nth-child(2){
    background: rgb(137, 110, 148);
}

section.open{
    background: red;

}

img{
    width: 90%;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section class="left" id="swup" >
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
    </section>
    <section  class="right" id="swup" >
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/400" alt="">
</section>

</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with `filter()` you just forgot to convert `sections` to Array first.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
const sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");

Array.from(sections).forEach(function(section) {
    section.addEventListener('click', function(el) {
        //console.log(sections, el)
        var diff = Array.from(sections).filter(element => element !== section)
        diff.forEach(function(otherEl) {
          otherEl.classList.remove("open")
        })
        section.classList.toggle("open")
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;

}

main{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;   
}

section{
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    padding-top: 2em;
    flex-grow: 2;
    flex-basis: 0;
    display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

section:nth-child(1){
    background-color: lightblue;
}

section:nth-child(2){
    background: rgb(137, 110, 148);
}

section.open{
    background: red;

}

img{
    width: 90%;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section class="left" id="swup" >
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
    </section>
    <section  class="right" id="swup" >
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/400" alt="">
</section>

</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `toggle` consider using `add` and `remove` on the class list instead. No need for `filter`.

```js
// Cache the sections
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

// Add listeners to them
sections.forEach(section => {
  section.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});

// Remove the open classes from all the sections first
// and then add one to the section that was clicked
function handleClick() {
  sections.forEach(section => section.classList.remove('open'));
  this.classList.add('open');
}
```

```css
main,section{display:flex}body{margin:0}main{width:100%;justify-content:center;flex-direction:row}section{transition:.3s ease-in-out;padding-top:2em;flex-grow:2;flex-basis:0;flex-direction:column}section:first-child{background-color:#add8e6}section:nth-child(2){background:#896e94}section.open{background:red}img{width:90%;align-self:center}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="left" id="swup">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
  </section>
  <section class="right" id="swup">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/400" alt="">
  </section>
</main>
```